# Redirection error in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

After adding data in location table, clicking on the save button should redirect it to list of data in location table.But ,it stays in the same page after adding.The same path is given to modify location,it works fine. whereas the same path does not redirect when add location.

```
function locationController($scope, $state, $rootScope, locationServices,$location, locations, location, primaryLocation, $stateParams,locationTypes, countries) {
    var vm = this;
    $scope.locations = locations.data;
    $scope.location = location.data;
    if (primaryLocation.data && primaryLocation.data[0]) 
        $scope.primaryLocation = primaryLocation.data[0];
    if (!$scope.location) {
        var location = {};
        if ($stateParams.accountId) {
            $scope.location = {accountId: $stateParams.accountId };
        } else {
            $scope.location = location;
        }
    }

    $rootScope.title = "Locations";
    $scope.locationslist = "views/locations.html";
   $scope.addOrModifyLocation = function (location) {

        if (location._id) {
            locationServices.modifyLocation(location).then(function (response) {
                $location.path('/account/locations/contacts/' + location.accountId + '/' +location.accountId);
               // $state.reload();
            })

        } else {
            location.status = 'ACTIVE';
            locationServices.addLocation(location).then(function (response) {
                $location.path('/account/locations/contacts/' + location.accountId + '/' +location.accountId);

            })
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want angular to know about your $location update, you have to do it like this :

```
  $rootScope.$apply(function() {
    $location.path("/my-path");   // path must start with leading /
  });
```

If you're using ui-router, a cleaner approach would be to use

```
$state.go('stateName', {'accountId' : location.accountId, });
```

edit :

If you have errors that happen during a state change, you can see it by adding the following code in your app after declaring your module :

```
angular.module("appName").run([
    "$rootScope",
    function ($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I am using ui-router. I have tried with your suggestion but still it does not redirects to the specified path.

Comment: I updated my answer by adding a way to debug errors that happen during routing.
Could you also update your question by adding the way you've declared the state you want to go to?